# I use a method in all of my classes every time. Is there a way to write this method only once?

Tags: java, android

I use the `isconnectInternet()` method to control the mobile phone internet connection in my all of classes. I do that, but it is duplicated in every class. How I can write it once and use it everywhere in the project?

```
  public boolean isConnected(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netinfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (netinfo != null && netinfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        return (mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting()) || (wifi != null && wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting());
    } else
        return false;
}
```

This is my method to control the internet

```
if(isConnected){

   if there is internet conn.
} 
else{
  there is no internet do samething

}
```

Comment: Use an interface, perhaps.

Comment: you want this method to write once in a file and you can access it from anywhere in code instead of writing this code in each file and class . Right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this method in another class and call it when you want it.

```
public class Common {

    public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {

         ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         NetworkInfo netinfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

              if (netinfo != null && netinfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
               android.net.NetworkInfo wifi=cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
               android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        return (mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting()) || (wifi != null && wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting());
    } else
        return false;
    }
}
```

and call it by class name and method name

```
if(Common.isConnected ){

   if there is internet conn.
 } 
 else{
     there is no internet do samething

 }
```

Comment: you were fast in it. I was writing it :(

Comment: I will try it and look result

Answer (score 0):

[Static Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods) are your friend in this case. Change:

```
public boolean isConnected(Context context) {
```

to:

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
```

This changes the method so that it no longer relies on an instance of a class, so you can access it from any other class. As a result, this changes your check method to:

```
if(MyClass.isConnected(context)){
    //if there is internet conn.
} 
else{
    //there is no internet do something
}
```

Bear in mind that this works in your particular example as you're only relying on a `context` that is passed in as an argument. If you declare a function as `static`, you'll no longer be able to access the member variables of that class unless they too are declared `static`.